# WMI - IIS 7 - Retrieve all website bindings

Tags: c#, iis-7, wmi

Im trying to find some sample code that shows how use the WMI ( using C#) to query a remote IIS 7 for all website bindings. 
I cant make heads or tails of all the classes/ name spaces and querys that need to be made to accomplish this.
If no sample code is available i would love some refrences to good documentation.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ServerManager.OpenRemote("serverName")` function to connect to an external IIS instance. (See the msdn article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).)

If you enumerate through `serverManager.Sites` collection you can then retrieve the `site.Bindings` property from each `Site` object to see the bindings that are active on that website.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by accessing the IIS metabase, using the System.DirectoryServices assembly.

For example, here you can enumerate through all of your sites and property configurations contained within those sites.

Add this reference to your project:

`using System.DirectoryServices`

```
// Assuming your Server Id is 1, and you are connecting to your local IIS.
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root");
foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in de.Children)
{
   foreach (PropertyValueCollection property in entry.Properties)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value {1}",property.PropertyName, property.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted this will only work if they have IIS6 Metabase compatability installed on the server. You should also always .Dispose() your COM objects :)